# Lead(II)chloride solubility in hot water

Tags: thermodynamics

I just went through my notes from last semester and remembered something my professor told me but only explained it very briefly. I tried to find anything about the topic on the net but couldn't find much. And I want to make sure that this information is nothing he just came up with but based on some actual literature.

So he was talking about the increased solublity in Lead(II)chloride when you heat the water. How he explained it was with the crystal structure of Lead(II)chloride where he said the lone pairs on the lead would take part in the coordination as well and whatever coordination polyhedron might form in that case (he had a selfdrawn picture of that) will have one edge which isn't very strong and likes to break at warmer temperatures which increases solublity.

Now that was all a little fast and I'd like to have some confirmation on that topic. Has anyone ever heard about this before?

Comment: Lead chloride is by no means unique in that regard. Most solid salts increase solubility with temperature. This has nothing to do with lone pairs.

Comment: I know I found that as well. The most common explanation for Lead Chloride is the same as for all other salts that become more soluble in warm water which is probably why I cannot find anything else on the topic. I meant more like is there really another effect that contributes to this based on the crystal structure of the compound?

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/42698/why-exception-is-noted-in-the-solubility-of-lead-salts